# OpenTok Unique Mute Image for Each Subscriber

Tags: javascript, opentok

I'm building a video conference platform with OpenTok for a virtual event I'm running. For this event I'm also collecting picture from my attendees. When they go on mute I'd like to show their individual pictures instead of the generic head image.

I know I can use `subscriber.setStyle('backgroundImageURI', imgData);` however that sets the same image for each subscriber, so would work in a 1-on-1 setting, but if I exceed that (which I will) it won't work. I also tried `publisher.setStyle('backgroundImageURI', imgData);` which changes the mute image for the publisher, but does not effect what the user on the other end sees.

I'd appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: Is there anybody out there? I'll keep digging and report back if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could listen to the [videoDisabled](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#.event:videoDisabled) event of the subscriber and hide the subscriber and display the image or display the image above the subscriber div.

Then also listen to the [videoEnabled](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#.event:videoEnabled) event to remove that image.

Comment: Definitely a good workaround solution I hadn't considered. Was hoping they had something built-in so I didn't have to do so much work, but I can probably figure it out. Thank you!